# Unity3D: Line renderer hidden by underneath object shader

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the attached images, there is an Earth object of radius 6.4, and an ISS orbit of radius 6.8. The camera is orthographic, with near/far set at 1/3000. In the first image the orbit line is rendered well, and on the second image the orbit line is hidden by the Earth although it is above the planet. For the line I am using a Unity LineRenderer. For the Earth it's a sphere mesh with 2 materials: - First material uses a surface shader, called "Custom/EarthGround" - Second material uses a vert+fragment shader, called "EPIC/Projector2" The first image uses only the first shader, and the second one, where the line is hidden, is using the two.

What do you think I am missing, likely in the second shader, that causes the earth to hide the line ?

Attaching the sub-shader properties excerpt below, as well as the images.

Shader #1, named "Custom/EarthGround" (excerpt):

```
          SubShader 
           {
             Tags
             {
                 "Queue"="Geometry"
                 "IgnoreProjector"="False"
                 "RenderType"="Opaque"
             }
             Cull Back
             ZWrite On
             ZTest LEqual
             ColorMask RGBA
             Fog{
             }
```

Shader #2, named "EPICProjector" (excerpt):

```
 Subshader { 
         Tags {"Queue"="Geometry"}
                 Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
         Pass {
              Name "PROJECTOR"
             Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

Shader #1 only - line not hidden:
[image: Shader #1 only - line not hidden]

Shader #1 + #2 - line hidden
[image: Shader #1 + #2 - line hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. I found that there is a RenderQueue field in the material inspector that overrides what's in the shader. So setting the RenderQueue to "Geometry" does fix the problem!

[image]